# Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

I have this protocol:

```
protocol ViewType {
    associatedtype T: ViewData.View
    var data:T! {get set}
}
```

`ViewData.View` is a class

I have a class called `TemplateLabel` that inherits `UILabel` and conforms to `ViewType`

```
class TemplateLabel:UILabel, ViewType {
    var data: ViewData.View.Label!
}
```

I get this `TemplateLabel` from storyboard as a `UIView` and try to cast the `UIView` into `ViewType` to assign the `data` property to it

```
let view = SB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view_label").view
if var v = view as? ViewType { // Error
    v.data = data // Error
}
```

But I get errors:

> Protocol 'ViewType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
>
> Member 'data' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'ViewType'; use a generic constraint instead

Comment: You should cast to a specific implementation, not to a constraint-protocol. Cast to `TemplateLabel`. And read more about protocols in Swift :)

Comment: @werediver I have a specific reason to not cast directly to TemplateLabel, it is to make things dynamic, this is just a short example

Comment: Then you need a generic method... I can show an example (in a few minutes). Another way is to fall into type-erasure, but that would be too deep, I think.

Comment: That would be nice, thats exactly what Im trying to make, a generic method x)

Comment: Hm, I was wrong. A generic method cannot solve this kind of problem, because generic methods are instantiated for particular types at the compile time, but your object type is unknown at the compile-time unless you cast it to a specific implementation.

Comment: I think its weird because the associatedType has a constraint and the 'data' I try to set is of the same type

Comment: Swift will not treat too different implementation of your constraint-protocol as compatible even if their associated types match. So no, that's not so weird. Such a protocols is not exactly what you expect them to be. They are more like templates for your particular implementations (not a polymorphism tool).

Comment: Watch this talk by Rob Napier to get insights into this problem- http://www.thedotpost.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for you, but that's pretty much bare code. I think it can *really* be useful in the defined context.

```
import UIKit

// Framework

/**
 * Intended usage:
 *
 *     enum AppStoryboard: BundledStoryboard {
 *
 *         case Login
 *         case Main
 *
 *         var storyboard: UIStoryboard {
 *             return UIStoryboard(name: "\(self)", bundle: nil)
 *         }
 *
 *     }
 */
protocol BundledStoryboard {

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard { get }

}

protocol StoryboardViewController {

    static var bundledStoryboard: BundledStoryboard { get }
    static var storyboardId: String { get }

    static func instantiateFromStoryboard() -> Self

}

extension StoryboardViewController {

    static var storyboardId: String { return "\(self)" }

    static func instantiateFromStoryboard() -> Self {
        return bundledStoryboard.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as! Self
    }

}

// Application specific

enum AppStoryboard: BundledStoryboard {

    //case Login
    case Main

    var storyboard: UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "\(self)", bundle: nil)
    }

}

extension StoryboardViewController {

    static var bundledStoryboard: BundledStoryboard { return AppStoryboard.Main }

}

// View-Model relation

protocol ViewType {

    associatedtype Model

    func loadModel(m: Model)

}

// ViewController

final class ViewController: UIViewController, StoryboardViewController, ViewType {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func loadModel(m: UIColor?) {
        view.backgroundColor = m // Strange example, yeah.
    }

}

// Then somewhere...

let vc = ViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
vc.loadModel(.redColor())
```

I don't think you really need any dynamic solution here. You must know what you're instantiating and what data it can receive.